# JQuery Lipsum generator not generating word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a website called lipsum.com which generates random text. I am trying to use jquery to  generate a word and save it to a variable. I found this[1]: http://sanderkorvemaker.nl/jquery/jLorem.php which could be really good but i am not sure why it is not working. Based on the example i have came up with solution and I have the javascript file in a folder called "Script" under my solution but I am still not getting any output to the screen.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
    <script src="Script/jquery.lorem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.ipsum').lorem({ type: 'paragraphs', amount: '4', ptags: true });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ipsum"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('.ipsum')` doesn't match anything.

Comment: What does that .ipsum mean? Is it looking for a reference there or something?

Comment: add <div class="ipsum"></div> inside the body tags.  the $('.ipsum') is looking for an element with a class of 'ipsum'

Comment: You probably ought to read about jQuery a bit. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I put this into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYwk2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a div with a class of "ipsum."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/jquery.lorem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.ipsum').lorem({ type: 'paragraphs', amount: '4', ptags: true });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="ipsum"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not getting any output with that unfortunately.

Comment: I forgot one quotation mark (text editor usually does it for me, heh).  try it like <div class="ipsum"></div>

Comment: Still not getting any output. I have my html file and then i have the js file within a folder called Script

Comment: alright, i found another error.  You didn't close the script tag that calls jquery.  change the line to: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I like this stuff, it's no problem!

Comment: You also have to include the css for ipsum which is defined on the demo page you gave